# Why does Porter Stemmer code not work in Lucene version 4.10.4?

Tags: java, lucene, stemming

I am writing a stemmer using a porter filter.

```
 public static String stemmer(final String unstemmedText) throws ParseException, IOException {

    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_4_10_4, new StringReader(unstemmedText));
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_4_10_4, tokenStream, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
    tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    CharTermAttribute charTermAttr = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(charTermAttr.toString());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I am getting the following exception:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:923)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:1133)
```

So after some googling I decided to call a reset on the token stream and end the stream after the processing.

```
https://thekandyancode.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/tokenizing-stopping-and-stemming-using-apache-lucene/
```

So my modification is:-

```
 tokenStream.reset();
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(charTermAttr.toString());
    }
 tokenStream.end();
```

Now I am getting this exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
```

So earlier code expects a reset and when I do it now it simply does not work. What do I do?

I am extremely dissapointed by how the lucene project is being developed. If contracts for resetting break because of sudden enforcement, developers will think twice before upgrading. Also the API is completely revamped across versions with convenient old classes like porter stemmers being deprecated. This makes lucene usage incredibly difficult. Please pull your socks together and architect this better.

Comment: Downgrading version to 4.1 resolved the issue. Seriously if things dont work dont publish it as a release.

Comment: Could you try to narrow down the version, by trying lets say version 4.6.x? interesting to see since when this behavior occurs.

Comment: plus 1 for "Please pull your socks together and architect this better"